# display a given value in a cell if the formula result is below a specified amount?

Tags: excel

I have been looking all over and can't seem to find a solution that really fits what I need. I have a basic excel formula (a variable multiplier determined by another formula result, times a fixed rate - $22 in this case).

This part works great, but the problem is that if that amount comes out to be less than $350, I need to make it display $350 in that cell (or another cell). One other thought I had was to modify the final calculation of the other cell (create an 'if' statement so if the value returned from the one cell, reference another cell with the fixed 350 amount).

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. I am a pretty novice excel user but can usually think my way around stuff. This one has me stumped though. I can provide the workbook if that might help clarify. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I must have hit that one by accident. I pulled it now, sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If your original formula is:

```
=A1*B1
```

then use:

```
=IF(A1*B1<350,350,A1*B1)
```

instead

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much! I figured it was something simple like that. Greatly appreciated!